# Target a function with QThread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, qthread

I'm aware of this structure

```py
class MyThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def run():
       # do stuff

t = MyThread()
t.start()
```

With regular `threading.Thread` you can do something like this:

```py
def stuff():
    # do stuff

t = threading.Thread(target=stuff)
t.start()
```

Any way to do this in pyqt5 with QThreads? Something like this:

```py
t = Qthread(target=stuff)
t.start()
```

I tried that but I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'target' is an unknown keyword argument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the function to a custom argument in the `__init__`, create an instance attribute for its reference and then run it in the `run`.

```
class MyThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, target=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.target = target
    
    def run(self):
        if self.target:
            self.target()

def stuff():
    # do something

t = MyThread(target=stuff)
t.start()
```

Be aware that access to UI elements is *not* allowed in external threads, so don't use the threaded function to do anything related to UI: reading values and properties is unreliable, and writing can cause your program to crash.

Comment: Thanks, Got you. But isn't there a built in way to do that in Qthread? (without creating a class)

Comment: @lordcommander not for simple functions. An alternative could be to create a QThread and connect its `started` signal to the function, but it's fundamentally the same thing and doesn't usually provide real benefits.

Comment: @musicamante Just some cosmetics: I know it's meant to be some pseudo-code, but I am not sure the code will run without adding "def run(self):".